# Cheeger constant and isoperimetric ratio

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isoperimetric-problems

$(S^2,g)$ is 2-dimensional sphere with Riemannian metric. Consider any curves $\gamma$ on $S^2$ dividing the total area $A$ into two parts $A_1+A_2 =A$. The isoperimetric ratio is
$$
C_s(\gamma)=\frac{L^2}{4\pi}(\frac{1}{A_1}+\frac{1}{A_2})
$$
where $L$ is the length of $\gamma$.   The Cheeger constant is
$$
h=\inf_{\gamma} \frac{L}{\min\{A_1, A_2\}}
$$
take the infimum over all curves $\gamma$ on $S^2$. Assume $\gamma_0$ attain $h$, namely
$
h=\frac{L(\gamma_0)}{\min\{A_1(\gamma_0), A_2(\gamma_0)\}}
$,
where $L(\gamma_0)$ is the length of $\gamma_0$, and $A_1(\gamma_0), A_2(\gamma_0)$  are the area divided by $\gamma_0$.    I feel
$$
C_s(\gamma_0) \le 1. \tag{1}
$$
I find this problem from  Hamilton's **An isoperimetric estimate for the Ricci flow on the two-sphere** (It is   the 9th paper of [Collected papers on Ricci flow](http://library.lol/main/e4b3107a8249e1765db358a82ccc50d8)).  In fact, when $\gamma$ is a small circle, $C_s(\gamma)$ will close $1$.

What I try:  If assuming $A_2\le A_1$, by variation, I get
$$
-\int_{\gamma_0} k_g ds =\frac{L^2}{A_2}
~~~\text{and}~~~
\int_{\gamma_0} K ds \le -\frac{L^3}{A_2^2}  
\tag{2}
$$
where $k_g$ is geodesic curvature of $\gamma_0$, $K$ is sectional curvature. But I still don't know how to get (1) from (2). Seemly, the Gauss-Bonnet can't relate the two integral of (2). What should I do?

**PS(2023-6-21):** I found an interesting example which may show the minimizer of Cheeger constant is not the minimizer of isoperimetric ratio.

> [image]

Rotate the left curve around the y axis to get the right surface which like a  witch hat. We have $h\in (0,9.9), r=\frac{1}{h+0.1}-0.1$ and
$$
\begin{align}
&L=2\pi(\frac{1}{h+0.1}-0.1) 
\\
&A_1=2\pi\ln 10-2\pi\ln(h+0.1)-2\pi+0.02\pi+0.2\pi h
\\
&A_2=2\pi\ln(h+0.1)-2\pi\ln0.1-0.2\pi h
\end{align}
$$
Using Mathematica I get

> [image]

Obviously, if the minimizer of Cheeger constant for  witch hat is circle parallel to the subface, the minimizer of Cheeger constant is not the minimizer of isoperimetric ratio.  Besides, there is another way to divid the hat which I did not calculate. Liking the picture below.

> [image]

Although it is a hat, if glue two hats together along the edge of the hat, we have $S^2$. I still don't know how to prove (1). Thanks for any help (answer or reference will do ).

Comment: Perhaps you can use [Papasoglu's bound](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2009-361-10/S0002-9947-09-04815-6/S0002-9947-09-04815-6.pdf) for the Cheeger constant, Proposition 2.3, Riemannian case